# Weird issue while testing R package: package `[package name]` found more than once, using the first from [file path]

Tags: r, testthat

I'm working on a somewhat complex package (that I unfortunately can't share) that involves a Shiny app, and it an issue has surfaced where I'm getting these warnings when testing:

`package [package name] found more than once, using the first from [file path]`

`In library(testthat) : package ‘testthat’ already present in search()`

The first one occurs because I'm using `system.file` to pull a file in `inst` that I use for testing.

I've tried to do some debugging with `.libPaths` and by forcing `system.file` to go to the `.libPaths` default with the `lib.loc` argument, but that doesn't do anything.

I've tried uninstalling the package, which works because then there are not multiple results for `find.package`.

It seems like testthat adds the current directory to the library paths while it's running, and this creates the issue with `system.file` and consequently, `find.package`.

I'm really confused as to what's causing this. I'm combing through the changes I've made and I can't seem to find anything. Any ideas are helpful. I've tried googling this error messages and all that comes up is the source.

Comment: Have you unistalled the package and then removed the folder in your library to get a clean install? Have you tried to use a different computer? Maybe rstudio.cloud? If that doesn't reveal the problem, you could try making a new package and copy over bit by bit from your source code, testing at each stage if `devtools:check()` reveals anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here was with changing the `option` setting for `verbose`. That caused more output to result from the code, which broke a lot of tests. I hope this helps someone in the future.